# AngularJS, how to make two input field's sum always equals to a third input whenever they dynamically change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a difficulty to me, there are three input fields, type number:

field 1____ (*required), field 2____, field 3____

how to use angularjs to achieve these:
I. if no input on field 2 and field 3, leave them blank;
II. whenever enter any of them, the other's value will be automatically updated so that their sum should always be the value in field 1;
III. they have validations like: cannot be greater than the value in field 1, or negative.

Comment: This doesn't sound like overly complex logic, but it's a bit much to work out in a single answer here with no code to start from.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="number" name="input1" ng-model="input1"/>
<input type="number" ng-change="input3 = (input1 && input2)?input1 - input2:0" name="input2" ng-model="input2"/>
<input type="number" ng-change="input2 = (input1 && input3)?input1 - input3:0" name="input3" ng-model="input3"/>
```

you can read up on [AngularJS's official form docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) to learn how to put validation for your fields too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it from the controller and take out logic from the partial.  This is not 100% working example but it is an option.  I just add a watch over the input fields(any change in any of the 3 input tags will trigger this watch), and set the html attribute max and min.

```
 <input type="number" 
    data-ng-model="fields[0]"
    min="1"
    max="2"
    required="fields.required" />
```

...do same for fields1 and fields2 or use ng-repeat

JS:

```
    $scope.fields= [0,0,0];
    $scope.fields.required = "required"; //this is if you generate the html tags with ng-repeat only
    $scope.$watchCollection('fields', function(newFields, oldFields) {
        //do your math and set
        function setFields(){

            $scope.fields[0] = newFields[0];
            $scope.fields[1] = y;
            $scope.fields[2] = z;
        }();
    });
```